Next.js turborepo + styled-components + package ui-kit
I am using NextJs and styled-components in my project.
I am using styles registry for my app from next js docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/styling/css-in-js#styled-components
In my app folder -> layout.tsx i wrap my children and styles load without delay, its correct
const RootLayout: FC<Props> = ({ children }): JSX.Element => {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body>
                <StyledComponentsRegistry>{children}</StyledComponentsRegistry>
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}

But I also have package - ui-kit and there are components like button, input etc.
For styling I also used styled-components, but when i load my app page (that uses button, for example) - styles for ui-kit components load with delay
I fix it with using this: i add registry.tsx file to ui-kit package and wrap every component like this
export function Button({
    children,
    onClick,
    type = 'button',
}: ButtonProps): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <StyledComponentsRegistry>
            <StyledButton type={type} onClick={onClick}>
                {children}
            </StyledButton>
        </StyledComponentsRegistry>
    )
}

But i dont like this decision
Do you know, how to registry styles without wrapping every component inside ui-kit?
I expect styled-components styles load correctly without delay and not to wrap every component inside ui-kit

does this also happen if you use next-yak ?
